# Trying to post json content with button in php

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm trying to post new data into my json file by using jquery by entering the values of the input but nothing happens when I do. I apologize in advance for this slightly dumb question and I'm very grateful for any help!

I'm very new to programming but I have no clue if this is even possible to do. Below is my 'index.php' file where my jquery and button is to add new data.

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="name">
    <input type="text" id="grade">
    <button id="btn">Add</button>
</body>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON('http://localhost/mytest/json.php', function(data) {

        for (i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (data[i].grade < 5) {

                document.write("<p style='color: red;'>Name: " + data[i].name + "<br>Grade: " + data[i].grade + "</p>");
            } else {

                document.write("<p style='color: green;'>Name: " + data[i].name + "<br>Grade: " + data[i].grade + "</p>");
            }
        }
    });

    // posting the orders



    $('#button').on('click', function() {

        var order = {
            name: $('#name').val(),
            grade: $('#grade').val(),
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost/mytest/json.php',
            data: order,
            success: function(newStudent) {

            }
        })
    });

});

</script>

</html>
```

Here below is the JSON file I created with PHP (json.php):

```js
<?php

$student1 = array(
    "name"=>"ali",
    "grade"=>"7"
);

$student2 = array(
    "name"=>"John",
    "grade"=>"4"
);

$student3 = array(
    "name"=>"Martha",
    "grade"=>"2"
);

$student4 = array(
    "name"=>"Jullie",
    "grade"=>"8"
);

$student5 = array(
    "name"=>"Morgan",
    "grade"=>"4"
);


$students = array($student1, $student2, $student3, $student4, $student5);

$j = json_encode($students); // we 'encode' the array into a JSON format
echo $j;

?>
```

Comment: This looks like a PHP question.  There is no logic in your php file to persist changes to the json it generates.

Comment: The PHP script needs to do something with `$_POST['name']` and `$_POST['grade']`.

Comment: Don't use `document.write()` after the page has finished loading. It will overwrite the entire page. Use DOM or jQuery methods to append the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello this is a fixed version of your code

1. Persisten data
2. Remove dumplicate code for pass grade
3. Create a div with students data(json content)

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
Name: <input type="text" id="name"><br>
Grade: <input type="text" id="grade"><br>
<button id="button">Add</button>
<div id="students">

</div>
</body>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // fill students div content with document ready
        updateStudents();

        $('#button').on('click', function () {

            var order = {
                name: $('#name').val(),
                grade: $('#grade').val(),
            }
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'json.php',
                data: order,
                success: function (newStudent) {
                    console.log("Success");
                    $("#students").append(setStudents($('#name').val(), $('#grade').val()));

                }
            })
        });

        function updateStudents() {
            $.getJSON('students.json', function (data) {

                for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    $("#students").append(setStudents(data[i].name, data[i].grade));

                }
            });
        }

        function setStudents(name, grade) {
            var color = 'green';
            if (grade < 5) {
                color = 'red';
            }
            return "<p style='color: " + color + ";'>Name: " + name + "<br>Grade: " + grade + "</p>"
        }

    });

</script>

</html>
```

**json.php**

```
<?php

$file = "students.json";

$content = file_get_contents($file); 

if ($content == null) {
    $data[] = $_POST;
    $jsonData = json_encode($data);
    file_put_contents($file, $jsonData);
} else {
    $data = $_POST;
    $tempArray = (array) json_decode($content);
    array_push($tempArray, $data);
    $jsonData = json_encode($tempArray);
    file_put_contents($file, $jsonData);

}
echo $jsonData;
```

**students.json**
Note: the file could be empty this is just some data

```
[{"name":"Pedro","grade":"10"},{"name":"Juan","grade":"10"},{"name":"Lopez","grade":"10"},{"name":"Maria","grade":"5"},{"name":"Miguel","grade":"5"},{"name":"Juana","grade":"4"},{"name":"hugo","grade":"8"},{"name":"Nano","grade":"2"}]
```

Comment: Wow! This helped solve my problem, thank you for you help!

Answer (score 0):

If nothing is happening, it may be that you need to change

```
$('#button')
```

to

```
$('#btn')
```

And, no dumb questions! We're all in this together. Best of luck to you.

Comment: This answer is incomplete in regards to all the issues in the OP.

Comment: @Taplar I don't understand the down vote. The issue seems to be nothing is happening when clicking the button. If that is correct, it is because the click event in the example is not attached to a selector that is on the page. Maybe I have misunderstood something.

Comment: So where in that php logic do you see the ability to update the json that is being generated, from inputs provided?  Because by answering and not addressing that issue, you are saying the **only** problem the OP has, is an incorrect event binding.

Comment: Ah, I understand what you're saying. I was only looking for what would cause 'nothing to happen'. I'll be sure to read issues more thoroughly from hence forth. Thank you!